# Need a way to copy shortened extra long strings

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have shortened an extra long string and used ellipsis to shorten it. is there a way to copy the whole string once it has been truncated?

I have created a codepen to assist:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMGoLL

```
    <h1>
   This little piggy went to market and this little piggy stayed home.
   </h1>

           h1 {
     width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

  padding: 20px;
   font-size: 1.3rem;
   margin: 0;
   background: white;
   resize: horizontal;
   }

  body {
   height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
   place-items: center;
   background: #ccc;
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When posting questions you should include all relevent code on your question just in case the third party ever removes it. Remember that SO is meant to be a historic dictionary of problems and solutions, not just a "Help me solve this." To that end they added [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so you can embed a working example directly in your quesiton instead of using jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: Additionally you didnt save your codepen, you just linked to codepen.io

Comment: yeah sure thing. i thought i did. i'll be more careful. thank you :)

Comment: @Marie fixed it.not sure how that happened

Comment: How are you trying to copy it? You can double click on it with your mouse and copy it, but I'm guessing you are looking for a way to do it with code.

Comment: @disinfor yes exactly. I am looking for a way to do it through code. there might be use cases when you cannot double click it like now.

Comment: Please update your question to include all your requirements for the copying, otherwise you're going to continue to get answers about double clicking the text (because that works). Are you looking for a single click solution? Can you use a button? These are some things you should address in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codepen with the solution. Updated to copy the content to clipboard.

```js
copy = function(){
    let element = document.getElementById("text");
    if(document.body.createTextRange) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
        document.execCommand("Copy");
  }
  else if(window.getSelection) {
    // other browsers

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(element);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    //alert("copied!") //alert among other methods can be used to auto deselect if you desire that
  }
}
```

```css
h1 {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
  resize: horizontal;
}

body {
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: #ccc;    
   }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1 id="text">
  This little piggy went to market and this little piggy stayed home.
</h1><button id="copyButton" onclick="copy()">Copy</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pretty good. Not exactly what i'm looking for but i think it will be a good start. thank you.

Comment: if you specify more what you need then maybe I can help further! :)

Comment: the issue with the current situation is that you cannot highlight text the whole way and copy using mouse hold as it will only copy  till  "this little piggy we." basically how can i go beyond those dots. hopefully that explains it.

Comment: @yojake42, isn't it possible by adding Mike's code in cooy () function to scrap contents inside an element?

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to the title element:

```
<h1 id="title">
  This little piggy went to market and this little piggy stayed home.
</h1>
```

Now you can access the text inside the element:

```
txt = document.getElementById('title').innerHTML
alert(txt)
```

Comment: Not quite. don't need an alert. Right now try highlighting the text and copy and paste, you will only get the words displayed.

Comment: how can i highlight the text and copy and still get the full text? also trying to avoid double click

Comment: It's just an example how to access the content of the element. I know you don't need the alert. if you want to copy the text to clipboard by script check this:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

if you want to highlight the text you have to change the style of the lelement:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Answer (score 0):

Actually when using ellipsis via CSS you are not truncating the string but just hiding to plain sight. So, double click, select all text untill ellipsis and copy ti clipboard. You are copying entire string.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do it through code. there might be use cases when you cannot double click it like now.